# How to capitalized a label text in iphone?

Tags: iphone

```
 NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    //Set the required date format

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];

    //Get the string date

    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [_lbldateLabel setText:str];
    [str uppercaseString];
```

i have the above code for displaying the month in label(_lbldateLabel),but i ant to show the  date in capital letter,now it shows "Dec",but i want "DEC".I put `[str uppercaseString];`,but nothing changes,How to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[str uppercaseString]` returns new string with uppercase characters, the original string remains unchanged. So you need to set the **new** string to your label:

```
[_lbldateLabel setText:[str uppercaseString]];
```